# How to put settings into groups

Tags: iphone, settings, settings.bundle

I am having issues with the settings bundle on iPhone. I want to create groups like shown in the image below (Measurement, Data Entry..etc.), however I can't work out how to do this.

I have found the 'Item' type 'Group' and I know how to create the individual settings, I just can't figure out how to put them into a group.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just have to specify an Item0 (Title = Measurement, Type = Group) then all the subsequent entries after that (Item1, Item2, etc) will be added under that group. This can all be entered in the plist editor of Xcode.

One thing to note is all items you add will appear under that group until you specify a new group.

Refer to the image attached.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't realise it was that simple! Is there a way to move the Items in the list up and down? Dragging and dropping doesn't seem to work.